# Switch case with default in handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to implement a custom `switch` `case` with `default` value with the help of the Register Helper function in HandlebarsJs.

Example:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    {{#switch value}} 
        {{#case 'a'}} A {{/case}} 
        {{#case 'b'}} B {{/case}} 
        {{#default 'C'}} {{/default}}
    {{/switch}}
</div>
```

**JS:**(The Register Helper function should work like the below pseudo code)

```
switch(val) {
  case 1:
     return 'A';
     break;
  case 2:
     return 'B';
     break;
  default:
     return 'C';
}
```

Comment: Why not use a helper function?

Comment: follow this link https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/927

Comment: @SameerAhmad yes with the helps of that page and other source I have wrote an answer below.

Comment: @chazsolo yes with the help of helper function only

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68516765/514329

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please go through the below examples, it will guide you step by step to add the switch case with default value and break in HandlebarsJs.

Use the link http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/ to test the code. *(Give `{}` 
 for Context)*

### Switch case

**Handlebars Template:**

```
<div>

        {{#switch 'a'}} 
            {{#case 'a'}} A {{/case}} 
            {{#case 'b'}} B {{/case}} 
        {{/switch}}

</div>
```

**Register Helper functions:**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('switch', function(value, options) {
  this.switch_value = value;
  return options.fn(this);
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('case', function(value, options) {
  if (value == this.switch_value) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
});
```

==========================================================================

### Switch case with default:

**Handlebars Template:**

```
<div>

        {{#switch 'a'}} 
            {{#case 'a'}} A {{/case}} 
            {{#case 'b'}} B {{/case}}
            {{#default '188'}} {{/default}}
        {{/switch}}

</div>
```

**Register Helper functions:**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('switch', function(value, options) {
  this.switch_value = value;
  return options.fn(this);
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('case', function(value, options) {
  if (value == this.switch_value) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('default', function(value, options) {
    return true; ///We can add condition if needs
});
```

==========================================================================

### Switch case with default and break

**Handlebars Template:**

```
<div>
        {{#switch 'a'}} 
            {{#case 'a'}} A {{/case}} 
            {{#case 'b'}} B {{/case}} 
            {{#default '188'}} {{/default}}
        {{/switch}}
</div>
```

**Register Helper functions:**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('switch', function(value, options) {
  this.switch_value = value;
  this.switch_break = false;
  return options.fn(this);
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('case', function(value, options) {
  if (value == this.switch_value) {
    this.switch_break = true;
    return options.fn(this);
  }
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('default', function(value, options) {
   if (this.switch_break == false) {
     return value;
   }
});
```

Comment: We can use this for else if condition too.
Example sudo code: 
if (a > b) {
   return 1;
}
else if (a > c) {
   return 2;
}
else {
   return 0;
}

Comment: This default doesnt work. .. how would you do this so that the default case renders what is inside the block, just as it does for the case function? Currently all it returns is the value '188' that you pass into it. I've tried updated the return options.fn(this) but it blows up, not sure why.
`{{#default}}<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">{{/default}}`

Comment: Please try this.
Handlebars.registerHelper('default', function(value, options) {
    return value;
});

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is an `if`-`else if`-`else` structure, consider to use the built-in `if`/`else` helpers (see [Helpers: Conditionals](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#conditionals) on "chained" conditionals) and define only the comparison operation in your own helper.

### Helper

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('isEqual', (value1, value2, options) => {
  return value1 === value2;
});
```

### Template

```
<div>
    {{#if (isEqual value 'a')}} 
        A
    {{else if (isEqual value 'b')}}
        B
    {{else}}
        C
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

---

Initially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68091411/1114532).

Answer (score 1):

I want to use #switch with #case and #default without setting a value for #default so I customize a popular answer.

**Switch case with default and break (via case -> default)**

Handlebars Template:

```
<div>
        {{#switch myvar}} 
            {{#case 'a'}} A {{/case}} 
            {{#case 'b'}} B {{/case}}
            {{#case 'default'}} Default output {{/case}}
        {{/switch}}

</div>
```

Register Helper functions:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('switch', function(value, options) {
  this.switch_value = value;
  this.switch_break = false;
  return options.fn(this);
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('case', function(value, options) {
  if (value == this.switch_value || (value == 'default' && this.switch_break == false)) {
     this.switch_break = true;
     return options.fn(this);
  }
});
```

In this solution you have to use **{{#case 'default'}**} instead of **{{#default '12345'}}** and the helper prints the content of #case, just like the others.

One helper less and a little more complexity in #case helper.

This works very fine for me.

Pay attention: put **{{#case 'default'}}** at the end of switch, and obviously the value 'default' cannot be in range of myvar.

Answer (score 0):

Just if you want to convert key to value.

```
module.exports = function(input, cases, values) {
  const caseArray = cases.split(',')
  const valueArray = values.split(',')
  const defaultValue = caseArray.length < valueArray.length ? valueArray[valueArray.length-1] : "";

  return caseArray.indexOf(input) > -1? valueArray[caseArray.indexOf(input)] : defaultValue 
};
```

```
{{switch "Y" "Y,N,D", "YES,NO,DELETED,-"}}  // YES
{{switch "Hi" "Y,N,D", "YES,NO,DELETED,-"}}  // -
```