# Handlebars simulate switch(case)

Tags: handlebars.js

I would like to simulate something like this:

```
{{#each this}}
   {{if @index == 0}}
      <li><img src="/Content/totem/images/0.png" alt="" height="200" width="200" /></li>
   {{else @index == 1}}
      <li><img src="/Content/totem/images/1.png" alt="" height="200" width="200" /></li>
   {{else if}}
      <li><img src="/Content/totem/images/2.png" alt="" height="200" width="200" /></li>
{{/each}}
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: can you not just do what they did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398408/switch-case-with-default-in-handlebars-js ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible using the below syntax as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398408/switch-case-with-default-in-handlebars-js) once the relevant helper function has been added.

**Helper Function**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('switch', function(value, options) {
  this.switch_value = value;
  return options.fn(this);
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('case', function(value, options) {
  if (value == this.switch_value) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
});
```

**Switch**

```
{{#switch this}} 
   {{#case 0}}
      <li><img src="/Content/totem/images/0.png" alt="" height="200" width="200" /></li>
   {{/case}}
   {{#case 1}}
      <li><img src="/Content/totem/images/1.png" alt="" height="200" width="200" /></li>
   {{/case}}
   {{#case 2}}
      <li><img src="/Content/totem/images/2.png" alt="" height="200" width="200" /></li>
   {{/case}}
{{/switch}}
```

Comment: I am not going to downvote this, but this is not correct. See what I posted in the comments. You need to register helper functions to achieve this.

Comment: @EvanGertis thanks for pointing this out - I've amended my answer to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a helper for the comparison. This sort of goes against the premise of a logic-less templating language as put forth by Mustache. However, it is practical.

Instead of defining a switch-case, I like to use the built-in `if`/`else` helpers (see [Helpers: Conditionals](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#conditionals) in the docs) and define only the comparison operation as a helper.

### Helper

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('isEqual', (value1, value2, options) => {
  return value1 === value2;
});
```

### Template

```
{{#each this}}
   {{#if (isEqual @index 0)}}
      <li><img src="/Content/totem/images/0.png" alt="" height="200" width="200" /></li>
   {{else if (isEqual @index 1)}}
      <li><img src="/Content/totem/images/1.png" alt="" height="200" width="200" /></li>
   {{else}}
      <li><img src="/Content/totem/images/2.png" alt="" height="200" width="200" /></li>
   {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://github.com/handlebars-lang/handlebars.js/issues/927#issuecomment-886163779) comment

```js
{{> (lookup . state) }}
{{#*inline "page1"}}page 1{{/inline}}
{{#*inline "page2"}}page 2{{/inline}}
{{#*inline "undefined"}}page 2{{/inline}}
```